# Error in parsing response in groovy script

Tags: groovy

getting this error while writing groovy assertion

```
Unable to determine the current character, it is not a string, number, array, or object The current character read is '' with an int value of 60 Unable to determine the current character, it is not a string, number, array, or object line number 1 index number 0
```

code for script is:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
def response=messageExchange.response.responseContent
def jsonOut=new JsonSlurper().parseText(response)
```

Comment: Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. What's in `response`?

Comment: Have a look in the response. Most likely you got some HTML back (either
because you have not specified in your request what content you want to
accept or due to some other problem (e.g. missing auth, ...)